# Spacy Dependency parsing for His word

Tags: spacy

How would I differentiate "His" word in any sentence as a Determiner or as a Pronoun in Spacy, because if I give word.dep_ for "his" word it will give as poss (possession modifier) in both cases.

for Example:
"Ronaldo was diagnosed with a deadly disease. His disease only came to public when he was at the age of 19" - here His is Pronoun.
"Hemanth and his friends went to Coorg" - here his is a Determiner.

Answer (score 0):

Use [coref](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) and replace 'his' or other words with name then apply the above thing coref will help you to identify which Pronouns is used for particular person and simply you can replace that